# Space complexity of IDDFS

Tags: algorithm, search, depth-first-search

I am struggling with the space complexity of *Iterative Deepening Depth First Search*. It seems to me that in the worst-case when the goal is the last node in the graph you will need to create the whole graph and therefore your space is *O(b<sup>m</sup>)* where *b* is the branching factor and *m* is the maximum depth. However, it is said to be *O(bm)*. Can someone please explain to me why this is the case. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may end up creating and visiting the whole graph, at one time or another, but you never need to hold it all in memory at the same time. At any point of time all you need to hold in memory is the path down to the current location, which gives you the m in bm. I presume the factor of b comes form holding the children of each node in the path, or equivalent information. In fact the Wikipedia entry at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search says

The time complexity of IDDFS is O ( b d ) {\displaystyle O(b^{d})} O(b^d) and its space complexity is O ( d ) {\displaystyle O(d)} O(d), where b {\displaystyle b} b is the branching factor and d {\displaystyle d} d is the depth of the shallowest goal.[2]